# Solr index retrieve raw values after applied analysers to a field

Tags: solr, solrj

How do you retrieve the indexed terms for a particular ID, e.g. retrieve terms that are actually stored in the DB with Index analyzers applied ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Luke Request Handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) to inspect a Lucene index on a lower level than the regular Solr interface. You can include a uniqueKey to retrieve information for a specific document.

I'm not familiar with any SolrJ integration for the Luke handler, but The Almight Search Engine might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to understand what happens as the content passes through the analysis chain, that's exactly what (Solr 4) Admin/Analysis screen shows. Including, step-by-step transformation for each component in the chain.

And you don't need to actual index any content, you can just type whatever text you are trying to comprehend the parse for.

Comment: for specific task, using Solr analysers and tokenizers, I want to transform articles into the tokens and then retrieve those tokens, to parse them with another ml algo.

Comment: If you are not actually doing any *searching*, you could probably just load Solr/Lucene analysis chain as a normal Java code and use that.

If you just want to process one string at a time, that's what the Analysis screen does, so you can just use the same handler too.

Comment: it would be lovely, but in the step before, I use Nutch to uploads 1000's of articles into Solr. Extracting that step would be quite tricky.